# Using frame.contains() with a rotated sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, rotation, frame, gamekit

Rotating a sprite doesn't rotate its frame, but instead enlarges it to accomodate the sprite's new dimensions, documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483066-calculateaccumulatedframe). The additional area around the sprite creates empty space.

When determining whether the rotated sprite contains another sprite, or a point of its, the `contains()` [function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1456316-contains) takes into account the empty `accumulatedFrame` space surrounding the rotated sprite.

How can you change the frame to match the sprite so this doesn't happen?

Comment: Did you try using SKPhysicsBody ?

Comment: Frame is bound by the axis, so it will always be relative to your x and y axis, not your character.  The variables inside of a frame are x,y,width,height not x1,y1,x2,y2.  You are going to either have to use an SKPhysicsBody, or create your own frame.  You can use matrix math for this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126967/rotating-a-rectangle-via-a-rotation-matrix

Answer (score 0):

One option is to position `SKNodes` at each corner of the square before its rotation, and then obtain their points using the [convert](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483056-convert) function afterwards. From there, you can draw a `UIBezierPath` between them, and check for accurate intersections using `contains()`.

The only problem with this is that the bezier will appear to move with a node when assigned to it, but the actual path is fixed and won't move.